# Graph theory: decompositions and Hamiltonian graph

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

13 people who are not superstitious wish to have dinner together at a round table for a few nights so that each person has different neighbours every night. For how many nights can they do this?
Please help!!!

Comment: What have you done so far?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it for $6$ nights. (After that everyone has had everyone else as a neighbour.) Identify the people with the numbers $0,1,2,\dots,12$. On the $d^\text{th}$ night (for $d=1,2,3,4,5,6$) seat $x$ next to $x\pm d\pmod{13}$. This works because $13$ is a prime number.

Comment: Wouldn't this work for any odd number?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_decomposition_(graph_theory)

Comment: Ah, I see. So, from the link, if we have $K_9$, we have $8+7+...+1= 36$ edges, and any seating arrangement is a cycle with $9$ edges. So we have $n=m=9$, and $n,m$ are odd. Since $9$ divides $36$ that means there is a cycle decomposition of $K_9$ into cycles of length $9$... so, am I seeing it right that we can't really use the theorem from the link as we need simple cycles?